# Output two separate nodegroups based on a shared property/value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, apply-templates

I'd like to start by saying I'm not super good at XPATH and that is the main reason I come to you guys for some assistance.

So I was working today on trying to "group", or so to say, some data from an XML file based on both of them sharing an ID. I managed, with help from a friend, to do this but it was rather long winded and I'm certain there must be an easier/cleaner way. Below is the XML, XSLT I used and the desired output:

```
 <Dude>
     <ID>768</ID>
     <Name>Mr Dude Man</Name>
 </Dude>
 ...
 <Basket>
      <CustomerID>768</CustomerID>
      <Purchases>
          <PurchasedItem>
              <ItemID>736383-2</ItemID>
              <ItemName>XSLT Training</ItemName>
              <ItemType>Book</ItemType>
              <ItemQuantity>2</ItemQuantity>
          </PurchasedItem>
          <PurchasedItem>
              <ItemID>736383-2</ItemID>
              <ItemName>Candy</ItemName>
              <ItemType>Consumable</ItemType>
              <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
          </PurchasedItem>
      </Purchases>
 </Basket>
```

XSLT I used:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Dude"/>

<xsl:template match="Dude">
    {Name} has purchased: 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Basket[Basket/CustomerID = ../Dude/ID]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Basket">
    {ItemName}
</xsl:template>
```

In the above example, each `Dude` can have a single basket and the basket has a `customerID` connected to it to identify the basket owner. Assume that both nodes are as deep as each other. How would I go about, using xpath on an `<apply-templates/>`, to produce the following result:

ps. Don't worry to much about the actual output, I just want to know the proper way of traversing an XML tree while matching on one of the nodes using `apply-templates`

```
Mr Dude Man has purchased: XSLT Training, Candy
```

EDIT: Forgot the XSLT I Used... Now the thing I am confused about is that is this the best way of doing this? With two separate matches. Also inside of a predicate do I need the `../` or does the predicate assume I'm starting at where I was matched eg: `Dude`

Comment: Can you post your input xml with context?

Comment: Could you post a more elaborate example? It seems that any dude/dudette could have more than one basket - what would be the expected result then? And what is the format of the result: XML, HTML or text?

Comment: _"Below is the XML, XSLT I used"_ I don't see any XSLT in your question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry yeah, I've updated the question. JLRishe, I'll update the question with my psuedo xslt

Comment: "*I've updated the question.*" I don't see that you have. Perhaps I am in a parallel universe?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I was just about to post it when i posted the comment, then I was distracted. Should be up to date now.

Comment: "*Dont worry to much about the actual output, I just want to know the proper way of traversing an XML tree while matching on one of the nodes using apply-templates*" I have no idea what that means. In general, you want use a **key** to link the basket to a customer and/or the customer to a basket. But you must decide in which direction (i.e. from which context) you want to work.

Comment: That is essentially what I was looking for. I have never used Key or current() before but they both look real slick so I will have to have a few goes. Thanks to you and the answerer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way to do cross-references like this is to use a key:

```
<xsl:key name='kBasket' match="Basket" use="CustomerID" />
```

Then you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Full/Path/To/Dude" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dude">
    {Name} has purchased: 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kBasket', ID)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Basket">
    <-- Any per-basket stuff could be output here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Purchases/PurchasedItem" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PurchasedItem">
    <xsl:value-of select="ItemName" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

The problem with your original attempt was that all the paths within your predicate were relative to `Basket` (and you didn't have the requisite path to get to `Basket` so the node-set was already empty at that point). The correct way to do that would be something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/Absolute/Path/To/Basket[CustomerID = current()/ID]"/>
```

but the key approach is preferable because it is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is exactly what I was asking for... Im just not very good at asking questions properly. Well done and happy christmas! :P

Comment: @JLRishe how do you avoid the 'Basket' getting matched again outside the 'Dude' template?

Comment: @Rnet The typical way would be to have templates earlier in the process direct the control flow toward the `Dude`s and not let it go down a route that leads to `Basket`s. For example: `<xsl:template select="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="/Path/To/Dude" /></xsl:template>`. If you just let the processing go without controlling it, you could wind up with the `Basket`s getting processed twice.